# After starting spyder: ImportError: cannot import name 'quick_guide'

Tags: python, ipython, importerror, spyder

When I start [spyder](/questions/tagged/spyder) the internal console pops up and gives the following "traceback":

```
>>> WARNING:traitlets:kernel died: 6.001837253570557
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'banner'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\base_frontend_mixin.py", line 163, in _dispatch
    handler(msg)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\jupyter_widget.py", line 296, in _handle_kernel_info_reply
    super(JupyterWidget, self)._started_channels()
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\frontend_widget.py", line 617, in _started_channels
    self.reset(clear=True)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\frontend_widget.py", line 661, in reset
    self._append_plain_text(self.banner)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\shell.py", line 280, in _banner_default
    return self.long_banner()
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\shell.py", line 91, in long_banner
    from IPython.core.usage import quick_guide
ImportError: cannot import name 'quick_guide'
```

The IPython console works without problems, it is just missing the "introduction text" (python version, help-commands).

Can I just ignore this exception or is there a way to fix this manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) This was fixed in Spyder **3.1.4** (just released). Please update to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! btw, `conda update` didn't work for me (ubuntu 16.04). Have no idea. But `pip` works.

Comment: Digress: the `jedi` problem is solved too. Thanks @Carlos!

Comment: I second @AndersonZhu . `conda update spyder` just says "All up to date". However `pip install -U spyder` solves the problem, and fixes the error.

Comment: That's because conda packages take a couple of days to be available. Besides, I really, really don't recommend you to use `pip` to update/install packages already available on conda. That's because several `pip` and `conda` packages are binary incompatible, so installing `pip` packages most certainly will break your Anaconda installation in the long run (not the case for Spyder, but certainly for Pandas, NumPy, Pyzmq, Matplotlib, etc).

Comment: As update: It's now avaiable on `conda` as well. And yes, it does fix the issue! Thank you.

Comment: There are other issues in 3.1.4 like kernel restarting while debugging under ipdb. What is the most stable version of Spyder available?

Answer (score 2):

To fix the exception manually one needs to change the last mentioned file in the traceback. In this case this one:

```
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\shell.py", line 91, in long_banner
    from IPython.core.usage import quick_guide
ImportError: cannot import name 'quick_guide'
```

and change `quick_guide` to `quick_reference as quick_guide`. One may need to restart Spyder but then the Exception disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

I solved:

Only use `conda install spyder=3.1.4` in your conda env.

Regards.

Comment: This answer doesn't add to the one given by spyder developer @Carlos Cordoba. Furthermore, using pip in a conda environment to install packages which are available on anaconda repositories should be strongly discouraged.

Comment: Depends, use one env for a IA application is recommended in some cases. If your env fail you can use a fresh clone of an original env, ou create a new env. Like a docker best practices....